# Combining two files into single file

Tags: json, shell

I have the below script which combines many json files into single one. But the first file is printed twice in final output file even though i have removed the first file from the list.Please advice how to print first file only once.
Bash Script is pasted below.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
declare -a jsons
jsons=(o-*.json) 
echo '[' > final.json
if [ ${#jsons[@]} -gt 0 ]; then 
cat "${jsons[0]}" >> final.json 
unset $jsons[0]                    
for f in "${jsons[@]}"; do # iterate over the rest
echo "," >>final.json
cat "$f" >>final.json
done
fi
echo ']' >>final.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `unset ${foo[0]}` to remove an item from an array variable in bash.

```
$ foo=(a b c)
$ echo "${foo[@]}"
a b c
$ unset ${foo[0]}
$ echo "${foo[@]}"
a b c
```

You'll need to reset the array itself using array slicing.

```
$ foo=("${foo[@]:1}")
$ echo "${foo[@]}"
b c
```

See: [How can I remove an element from an array completely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68322/how-can-i-remove-an-element-from-an-array-completely)

Comment: changed the unset command to this: $jsons = ("${jsons[@]:1}") but it throws below error line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 10: `$jsons = ("${jsons[@]:1}")

Comment: Spaces matter in bash, and when assigning a variable you shouldn't put `$` at the beginning. Rather than `$jsons = (...` you should have `jsons=(...`.